# Error while trying to rename files using C#

Tags: c#, foreach, rename

I have the following code to rename files in the following tree as from *00000001.pdf* to the last file with this 8 character left padding, e.g: *00000100.pdf*

1. Folder1

   - subfolder1

     1. childfolder1

        - pdffile1
        - pdffile2
     2. childfolder2

        - pdffile3
        - pdffile4
   - subfolder2

     1. childfolder3

        - pdffile5
        - pdffile6

But for some reason in some of those child folders it keeps renaming them with no end.
Some times it just jumps to another number, as if it was an async operation. But if I stop and start again it goes okay until the second next folder, when it messes up again.
But this error only happened within 19 folders.
Indeed their pdf names are different from the others, but I don't see how it is related.
The other files were named something like *"DOCUMENT_01"* and so on, but these are:
*0000000100000001.pdf
0000000200000001.pdf
0000000300000001.pdf*
etc

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Digite a pasta 'pai' onde serão buscados pdfs dentro das pastas 'filhas':");
            string path = Console.ReadLine();
            foreach (string dir in Directory.EnumerateDirectories(path))
            {

                foreach (string subdir in Directory.EnumerateDirectories(dir))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"{dir} - {subdir}");
                    int n = 1;
                    foreach (string pdffile in Directory.EnumerateFiles(subdir, "*.pdf", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
                    {                                  
                        Console.WriteLine(n.ToString().PadLeft(8, '0') + "  " + new FileInfo(pdffile).Length);
                        File.Move(pdffile, subdir + $"\\{n.ToString().PadLeft(8, '0')}.pdf");
                        n++;

                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("\n\n");
                }
            }
        }
```

What could be going wrong?
It should await for the File.Move method to end to add the n + 1 and then moving to the next pdffile as a synchronous operation. So why does it jumps numbers after a random time and why it keeps going forever other times?
And just to remember, if I stop the program and start again and put the folder that was messed up as the first one, it goes ok and only when it goes to the next folder, or the folder after next that it start to give me this error again.

Hope that I could make myself clear... Thanks for your attention!

EDIT: will try using FileInfo class to give me the parent folder with the SearchOption.AllDirectories option and exclude this 3 stage loop plus actually working for any kind of tree structure
EDIT2: Tried, worked as a "tree indepent" script but getting the same result with the files name after the first folder... As it's really fast, in 3 seconds it goes from *00000169.pdf* to *00006239.pdf* in a folder with just 330 items.

Comment: `Directory.EnumerateFiles(dir)` will not be happy if the directory contents changes while enumerating. You should materialize the collection by appending a `ToList`: `Directory.EnumerateFiles(dir).ToList()`

Comment: Oh, I will try! Thanks! But why in only these specific folders? 
I used wrongly as that in another +/-30 folders but the error didn't happen

Comment: Could be file size taking longer to move and I don't think File.Move waits for the operation to be done.

Comment: It worked @KlausGütter! Danke sehr!
And thanks @Matt, strange behavior, but at least I won't have to deal with it anymore!

Comment: @JohnG as in the documentation _Specifies whether to search the current directory, or the current directory and all subdirectories._ , so i really thought it wouldn't make a difference, but perhaps it did. Anyway, I changed the loops that was making the script work just in that special case of folder->subfolder->childfolder->pdffile. I used FileInfo.DirectoryName and an if clause to check when to return the enumeration to 00000001

Comment: After your last edit it is not clear any more what your problem was and what was the solution. You might want to add the solution as answer and not by editing the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer as Klaus Gütter helped me, I just added .ToList() to the Directory.EnumerateFiles so it made a fixed list first, and then made the foreach for each file

It will rename every pdf within the folder and it's subfolders

```
            Console.WriteLine("Type the folder you want to start with:");
            string path = Console.ReadLine();
            string dir = "";
            int n = 1;
            foreach (string pdffile in Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*.pdf", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList())
            {

                FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(pdffile);
                if (fi.DirectoryName == dir)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\t" + n.ToString().PadLeft(8, '0'));
                    File.Move(pdffile, dir + $"\\{n.ToString().PadLeft(8, '0')}.pdf");
                    n++;
                }

                else
                {
                    n = 1;
                    dir = fi.DirectoryName;
                    Console.WriteLine("\n\n" + dir);
                    File.Move(pdffile, dir + $"\\{n.ToString().PadLeft(8, '0')}.pdf");
                    Console.WriteLine("\t" + n.ToString().PadLeft(8, '0'));
                    n++;

                }

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

As commented already, it is not a good idea to move or rename files “WHILE” the code is enumerating though the list of those files as the posted code appears to do. This will cause obvious problems and you should simply mark the files somehow, then later come back and rename or move them.

More importantly, the big issue related to renaming/moving files is exactly as you describe with your current issue. The problem is that the errors are erratic and not consistent. Making it very difficult to trace. However, the problems you describe are classic trademarks of moving/renaming files while enumerating through those files.

With that said, the best way and easiest way to traverse an unknown number of folder levels given a starting folder is by using recursion. In a lot of cases, recursion can be avoided with some well though out loops, however when we do not know how many levels of folders there are, then, using a simple loop or `foreach` loop paradigm may be doable, however, you will most likely be adding variables and code that only makes this more complex. This is shown in the current code with the addition of the `dir` variable to keep track of “when” a different folder is used. Recursion is suited ideally for this situation.

In this case, this recursive method will be called ONCE for each folder and subfolders from a given “starting” folder location. This means that each time this recursive method is called is when a different folder is beginning to be processed. So `n` would always start at 1 and we do not need to keep track of the current folders path.

So the signature of this method will take a `DirectoryFolder` object as a “starting” folder. First we create some variables; a `FileInfo` array `pdffiles` to hold the pdf files in the given folder; in addition to a `DirectoryInfo` array `foldersInThisFolder` to hold all the other folders in this starting folder. Lastly an `int n` to index the files as the posted code is doing.

Next we get all the pdf files in this “starting” folder. If there are pdf files in this folder, then we loop through those files and process them. Next, we get all the other folders in this “starting” folder. Then start a loop through each folder. For each folder in this collection we will make the recursive call back to this method using the next folder as the “starting” folder, then the whole process continues until the loop through those folders ends.

```
static void TraverseDirectoryTree(DirectoryInfo startingFolder) {
  FileInfo[] pdffiles = null;
  DirectoryInfo[] foldersInThisFolder = null;
  int n = 1;
  Console.WriteLine(startingFolder.FullName);
  // get all the pdf files in this folder
  try {
    pdffiles = startingFolder.GetFiles("*.pdf");
  }
  catch (Exception e) {
    // you may want to catch specific exceptions
    // however in this example we do not care what
    // the exception is, we will simply ignore this.
    // in most cases pdffiles will be null if an exception is thrown
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
  }
  if (pdffiles != null) {
    foreach (FileInfo pdffile in pdffiles) {
      Console.WriteLine(pdffile.FullName + " -> " + n.ToString().PadLeft(8, '0') + "  " + pdffile.Length);
      //File.Move(pdffile.FullName, pdffile.DirectoryName + $"\\{n.ToString().PadLeft(8, '0')}.pdf");
      // add file path to a list of files to rename later?
      n++;
    }
    // start over wiith the sub folders in this folder
    foldersInThisFolder = startingFolder.GetDirectories();
    foreach (DirectoryInfo dirInfo in foldersInThisFolder) {
      TraverseDirectoryTree(dirInfo);
    }
  }
}
```

Usage…

```
Console.WriteLine("Type the folder you want to start with:");
string path = Console.ReadLine();
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(path);
TraverseDirectoryTree(di);
```

Edit… after further testing it appears that what you are wanting to do is simply “rename” the pdf files. As suggested a simple solution is to save the files that we want to rename, then, after we collect the files we want to rename, we simply loop through those files and rename them. This should eliminate any problems by renaming files while enumerating though the files collection.

To help, I created a `Dictionary<string, int>` called `filesToRename`. While recursively looping through all the folders, we will add the full path of each pdf file we want to rename as the Key and the int value `n` as the Value. After the dictionary is filled we would simply loop through it and rename the files.

```
private static Dictionary<string, int> filesToRename = new Dictionary<string, int>();
```

Then replace the commented-out line in the recursive method `TraverseDirectoryTree`…

```
//File.Move(pdffile.FullName, pdffile.DirectoryName + $"\\{n.ToString().PadLeft(8, '0')}.pdf");
```

With…

```
filesToRename.Add(pdffile.FullName, n);
```

Then after the dictionary is filled we would loop through it and rename the files, something like…

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(path);
TraverseDirectoryTree(di);
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> kvp in filesToRename) {
  int index = kvp.Key.ToString().LastIndexOf(@"\");
  string dir = kvp.Key.ToString().Substring(0, index);
  File.Move(kvp.Key, dir + $"\\{kvp.Value.ToString().PadLeft(8, '0')}.pdf");
}
```

I am hoping this makes sense…

Comment: First of all thank you very very much for this "c# class" for me hehehe I understood a lot! I  will also check if it has a better perfomance from just adding .ToList() to the Directory.EnumerateFiles(dir). But I understood a lot! I will post the final code that worked for me as answer just because it also worked. Thanks a lot again!

Comment: And sorry I don't have 15 reputation to cast a vote, but it said it was recorded hehehe

Comment: If you simply save the pdf’s full file name and path, then you will have to write the code to parse out which file is in which directory. In other words, you have a list of files and paths, however, you will NOT know which file is 000001.pdf, 000002.pdf or 000003.pdf etc.…, without adding code to parse out which folder each file belongs to. If you “save” the pdf index (1, 2, 3) with each file, then you do not have to keep track of which folder each pdf file belongs to.